# Using variance ratios to test for mean reversion

Tags: time-series, r

Can you use the variance ratio test to determine whether or not a time series is mean reverting? I'm using the `Lo.Mac` function in the `vrtest` library in `R`.

I've used the test to reject geometric Brownian motion as a price process. Does that indicate that I have a mean reverting process or does it only indicate that the assumptions of geometric Brownian motion are not satisfied?

My plot of variance ratios looks like this:
[image]

I don't quite understand the interpretation of this plot!

Note: I don't want to use a unit root test for stationarity because the process has nonconstant variance. It is not second order stationary although I believe that it is mean reverting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It only indicates that the null hypothesis of uncorrelated increments is violated.

For the sake of simplicity, assume a time series is stationary. Then a sufficient statistic for arbitrary variance ratios is its covariance function. In general, a given deviation from the null can originate from different covariance functions, which in turn, entails that making any specific claim about mean reversion is not trivial. I find that this point is often overlooked in the financial literature. I expect that when phrased properly a similar statement can be made about non-stationary series.

That being said, mapping abnormal variance ratios to mean reversion/trend following is not impossible but it requires making specific assumptions about the alternative model.

Comment: I tend to agree with you. However, I found the following quote: "The mean values of the individual firm variance ratios are shown in Table
5. They suggest some long-horizon mean reversion for individual stock prices." Page 19 of http://www.albany.edu/faculty/faugere/PhDcourse/meanreversion1.pdf I'm having trouble understanding why certain variance ratios would imply mean reversion.

Comment: In the abstract of the same paper: "It demonstrates that variance ratios are among the most
powerful tests for detecting mean reversion in stock prices."

Comment: I updated my answer to address some of your comments.

Answer (score 9):

of course you can use this test to elaborate on this matter. Basically this test measures the ratio of variance of series in period `tn` to `n*variance` of `t` preriod

$\frac{Var(tn)}{nVar(t)}$

in short:

- constant ratio for random walk
- increasing for series with trend
- decreasing for mean reverting process, more decreasing (faster) - better mean reversion

[image]

[image]